# AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN doesn't called after AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT after a phone call

Tags: java, android

I've got a typical `onAudioFocusChange` code in my game.

```
@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    switch (focusChange) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            Log.i(TAG,"AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN");
            mHasAudioFocus = requestAudioFocus();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            Log.i(TAG,"AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS");
            abandonAudioFocus();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            Log.i(TAG,"AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");
            abandonAudioFocus();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            Log.i(TAG,"AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK");
            abandonAudioFocus();
            break;
        default:
            Log.i(TAG,"Unrecognized audiofocus change");
    }
```

The issue is, that when a floating window appears on *Samsung* phones the application receives `AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT` message, but when this window is closed, no message comes to the application.

[image]

Here are relevant log lines:

```
13:20:53.253   770  7745 I MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  requestAudioFocus() from AudioFocus_For_Phone_Ring_And_Calls
13:20:53.253 14499 14499 I com.js.helpers.JSNativeActivity: AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT
13:20:53.253 14499 14499 I com.js.helpers.JSNativeActivity: abandonAudioFocus()
13:20:53.253 14499 14499 I JSNativeActivity: onAbandonAudioFocus
13:20:53.253   770  1508 I MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from android.media.AudioManager$42599770com.js.helpers.JSNativeActivity$4252c788
13:20:53.253   770  1508 I MediaFocusControl: AudioFocus  removeFocusStackEntry(): removing entry for android.media.AudioManager$42599770com.js.helpers.JSNativeActivity$4252c788
13:21:01.383   770  1220 I MediaFocusControl:  AudioFocus  abandonAudioFocus() from AudioFocus_For_Phone_Ring_And_Calls
```

Any ideas how to catch closing of this window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key sentence was [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/08/respecting-audio-focus.html).
*Note: The system will not grant audio focus (AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED) if there is a phone call currently in process and the application will not receive AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN after the call ends.*

So, this is an expected behavior, and I decided to create a timer and just request audio focus when it ends.

My current code is:

```
@Override
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
    switch (focusChange) {
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
            Log.d(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN");
            mHasAudioFocus = requestAudioFocus();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
            Log.d(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS");
            abandonAudioFocus();
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
            Log.d(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");
            abandonAudioFocus();
            startAudioFocusCountdownTimer(); 
            break;
        case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
            Log.d(TAG, "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK");
            abandonAudioFocus();
            startAudioFocusCountdownTimer(); 
            break;
        default:
            Log.d(TAG, "Unrecognized audiofocus change");
    }
}

private void startAudioFocusCountdownTimer() {
     new CountDownTimer(2000, 2000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // do nothing
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            mHasAudioFocus = requestAudioFocus();
            if (!mHasAudioFocus)
                startAudioFocusCountdownTimer();
        }
    }.start();
}
```