# what happens with onAudioFocusChange when a phone call ends

Tags: android

I am a bit confused because of this question [AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN doesn't called after AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT after a phone call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848596/audiofocus-gain-doesnt-called-after-audiofocus-loss-transient-after-a-phone-cal)

I don't believe in "Busy Waiting" solution. I think that AudioManager changes the state to AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN

And this question supports my viewpoint [AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS called after a phone call in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334110/audiofocus-loss-called-after-a-phone-call-in-android)

but when I tried, it never occurs to have the case of AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN

```
   AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

the request sent by

```
am.requestAudioFocus(af, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

and

```
 OnAudioFocusChangeListener af = this;
```

and

```
public void onAudioFocusChange(int i) {
    Log.d("AudioChanged", i + "");
    if (i == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
        am.abandonAudioFocus(this);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION));
    }  else if (i == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) {
        am.abandonAudioFocus(this);
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION));
        Log.d("loss transient", "AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT");

    } else if (i == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
        Log.d("gain ", "AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN");
        startPlaying();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't `abandonAudioFocus()` when `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT` or when `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS`, it happens automatically (the audio focus is passed to the new application that request audio focus, you just get the callback and you shoudn't abandon the request for audio focus becuase in case of a phone call you want to play again your music, what you should do is in case of `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS`, stop your `MediaPlayer` and that's all and in case of `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT` pause your `MediaPlayer` and when the phone call ends you automatically will get a call to `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN` and then you should play again your `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Thank you for your help I removed abandonAudioFocus()

Comment: But this was not my problem, my problem that nothing happens when the call ends, when the call occurrs I receive AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT but eventually I don't receive AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN when call ends

Comment: maybe you abandon your audio focus somewhere else that prevents the callback to AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN.

Comment: Same thing happens in google sample [Universal Android Music Player Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer), aftef phone call, callback with AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN was not called. Not every time but 1 on 4 calls it happens.